# Eclipse build command: "./configure && make"

Tags: eclipse, build, makefile, command

I downloaded an open source project and it says that to build the project, I need to type "./configure && make" under the project directory.

I typed it in the terminal and built it successfully. But I didn't know how to do the same thing with Eclipse.

I tried to right click the Makefile in the Project Explore -> Make Targets -> Build -> Add a new one with target name be "all" and build command "/path/to/configure && make", the output was 'unrecognized option "&&"'.

Answer (score 4):

You can run a shell like `bash` and specify the combination of commands you want to run:

```
bash -c "./configure && make"
```

Answer (score 0):

That project is assuming that you're using a sane terminal. Eclpise isn't sane. You need to run two commands, the first one being `./configure`. and the second being `make`. Of course, if the first command fails, we can only hope Eclipse is smart enough to realize it, as that's the purpose of the `&&` in the original command - not executing the second command if the first failed.

Comment: How can I have to command in the build command field? I tried comma, space...but it didn't work.